# Pipe rspamadm pw

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

I'm using rspamd in a Script and I'm trying to get a passwort hash via

```
rspamadm pw
```

My Idea was to pipe a passwort:

```
echo "test123"|rspamadm pw
```

But it doesnt work, it tells me to enter the passphrase, so the pipe doesnt work at all...

After that, i have to save that hash into a var like:

```
rspamadm_passwort_hash=$(echo "test123"|rspamadm pw)
```

smth like this, but with the working pipe :)

have a great christmas day :)

Answer (score 0):

Reading the -help can help sometimes :O

```
rspamadm_passwort_hash=$(rspamadm pw -p test123)
```

solved it...